# Google Maps API v2 legal notices String too much long

Tags: android, google-maps, android-alertdialog

I'm trying to add, in my android app, the legal notices for Google Maps v2 API, that can be obtained calling: `GooglePlayServicesUtil.getOpenSourceSoftwareLicenseInfo()`

So, my code is the following:

```
String LicenseInfo = GooglePlayServicesUtil
      .getOpenSourceSoftwareLicenseInfo(getApplicationContext());

AlertDialog.Builder LicenseDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MyActivity.this);
LicenseDialog.setTitle("Lagal Notices");
LicenseDialog.setMessage(LicenseInfo);
LicenseDialog.show();
```

But when I execute this code, the system required about 10 seconds before the dialog is shown (considering that my device is a OnePlus One, it seems pretty strange) .

If I try to replace the LicenseInfo with a simple (shorter) string, the Dialog is open pretty fast. So I think that the problem is the length of the legal notices information retrieved from the Google play utils.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I would try to load your message in a background thread, put a progress bar in your dialog, when your message is done loading set your message for your dialog to that message and call it a day. Takes some time for devices to load long text.

Comment: I know this may be a solution, but I'm really surprised that to show the legal need to do so much work.

Comment: What exactly is LicenseInfo? There may be other ways to do it that are less involved but dumping a lot of data into a dynamically generated view can be a relatively heavy process for your device.

Comment: The officiale web site  says: "If you use the Google Maps Android API in your application, you must include the Google Play Services attribution text as part of a "Legal Notices" section in your application. Including legal notices as an independent menu item, or as part of an "About" menu item, is recommended. The attribution text is available by making a call to GooglePlayServicesUtil.getOpenSourceSoftwareLicenseInfo."

Comment: Sorry didn't see the whole question, was scrolled down too far and forgot that you set it above. I am making a bold assumption in saying that I think that getting the String is what is actually taking a second, not actually loading it into your view. If that is the case, you could load the String into a shared preference or something on initial load to make it easier to pull when you need to. Again, completely assuming that is the issue.

Comment: No, I tried to set a Log and timer: the execution of all the code requires a fraction of second. also the show() method of the AlertDialog is immediately executed, but then about 10 seconds are required for showing the dialog. We are talking about a string with length 50688.

Comment: I am going to be honest that does seem weird to me. It shouldn't take that long to build that. You might want to try creating a separate Activity and setting its theme to a dialog to see if you can't manage things more efficiently. I would try to see if there is anything on an alertdialog builder getting hung up on long text too, haven't experienced that myself before.

Comment: Thank you, zgc7009. Maybe I'll remove that legal notice.

Comment: @Joseph82 I don't think removing the legal notice is the answer. It's there for a reason

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, but I found this on GitHub and based my solution on it. This does help but when the alert dialog shows, there is still a small hang on the UI thread but only for a few seconds.

https://github.com/wf9a5m75/phonegap-googlemaps-plugin/blob/master/src/android/plugin/google/maps/AsyncLicenseInfo.java

```
private class AsyncLoadLicenseInfo extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,AlertDialog.Builder>
{

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        progressDialog.setMessage(context.getResources().getString(R.string.LegalNoticesLoading));
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected AlertDialog.Builder doInBackground(Void... params)
    {
        String googleAttribution = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getOpenSourceSoftwareLicenseInfo(context);
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        builder
                .setTitle(context.getResources().getString(R.string.AboutLegalNotices))
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setMessage(googleAttribution)
                .setPositiveButton(context.getResources().getString(R.string.Close),null);

        return builder;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(AlertDialog.Builder builder)
    {

        AlertDialog attributionDialog = builder.create();
        attributionDialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog)
            {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                progressDialog = null;

            }
        });

        attributionDialog.show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As tasomaniac suggested, using `WebView` instead of `TextView` works without problems - there is just a small delay.

Here is the complete code to show the dialog:

```
private void legalDialog(){

        String licenseInfo =  GooglePlayServicesUtil.getOpenSourceSoftwareLicenseInfo(this);
        licenseInfo = licenseInfo.replace("\n", "<br/>");

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle(R.string.legal_notice);

        WebView webView = new WebView(this);
        webView.loadData("<html><body>"+licenseInfo+"</body></html>", "text/html", "utf-8");
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setDefaultFontSize(12);

        builder.setView(webView);
        builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.dialog_close, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        final AlertDialog createDialog = builder.create();
        createDialog.show();

    }
```

Make sure to check if `GooglePlayServicesUtil.getOpenSourceSoftwareLicenseInfo(this)` doesn't return `null`, before calling `legalDialog()`.

Answer (score 1):

On a Motorola G5 running Android 6 the licence string returned by `GooglePlayServicesUtil.getOpenSourceSoftwareLicenseInfo()` (or more recently `GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().getOpenSourceSoftwareLicenseInfo(getActivity())`) is over 600,000 characters long. The delay occurs when loading the string into the `TextView`, which *must* be done on the UI thread.

[LongStringLoader](https://github.com/Penrillian/LongStringLoader) may be a solution to this. Full disclosure - I worked on the development team.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution would be to use a `WebView` instead of a `TextView`. 
You can have a really small Html template and you can fill its body with license text returned by

`String result =  GooglePlayServicesUtil.getOpenSourceSoftwareLicenseInfo(this);`

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to show a progress dialog because the UI freezes. Plus the time consuming part was when dialog.show() took place and that could not be done on a background thread. Instead, I changed the text of the legal notices link to "Please wait" and then showed up the dialog with the legal notice. When the dialog dismissed I changed the text back to "Legal Notices" (Ofcourse the new dialog took up the whole screen where my background text was covered. If not then use dialog.setOnShowListener to change the text to/from Please Wait)

```
legalNoticeTV.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            legalNoticeTV.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.please_wait));
            legalNoticeTV.setEnabled(false);

            String result =  GooglePlayServicesUtil.getOpenSourceSoftwareLicenseInfo(this);
            TextView tv = new TextView(this);
            tv.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.dialogbackgroundcolorgrey));
            tv.setText(result);
            tv.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
            ScrollView sc = new ScrollView(this);
            sc.addView(tv);

            legalNotice = new Dialog(this, R.style.DialogNoTitle);

            legalNotice .requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

            legalNotice.setContentView(sc);
            legalNotice.show();
            legalNotice.setOnDismissListener(new OnDismissListener() {

                @Override
                public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                    legalNoticeTV.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.legal_notices));
                    legalNoticeTV.setEnabled(true);
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

While using WebView as in lenooh's answer, it is better to use `TextUtils.htmlEncode(licenseInfo)` instead of manually converting string to HTML string.

```
String licenseInfo =  GooglePlayServicesUtil.getOpenSourceSoftwareLicenseInfo(this);
licenseInfo = TextUtils.htmlEncode(licenseInfo);
```